# Can Taq polymerase be stored with PCR primers?

Tags: genetics, molecular-biology, dna, pcr

I don't think it's possible for TAQ to be stored with the primers, but I'm not sure. This storage wouldn't be long-term (a few days, or a week at most). Thoughts?

Comment: I have kept PCR stock solutions containing everything except DNA template for days to weeks at 4°C, and it works fine, at least for screening purposes (say, *E. coli* colony PCR or purified plasmid templates).

Comment: @gaspanic -20C would be ideal, though, especially for the dNTPs.

Comment: @MattDMo dNTPs are perfectly stable for months at 4°C, see for example [here](https://www.carlroth.com/medias/Info-Brochure-Nukleotides-EN.pdf?context=bWFzdGVyfHRlY2huaWNhbERvY3VtZW50c3wyMzA4MTl8YXBwbGljYXRpb24vcGRmfHRlY2huaWNhbERvY3VtZW50cy9oZjcvaGExLzg5NzY2MzAwNTQ5NDIucGRmfDgyMzE3M2VjNGI0NWExY2ViMzJjNjVkNjY5YTFmYjIxMjNhMjZhMzk1NDk2NjQxYzRjMWVkZmI3YjM0OWI3NGE) and [here](https://greenbioresearch.com/product/dntp-mix-25-mm-thermostable-pcr-qrt-pcr/). I always keep an aliquot of my dNTP stock solution at 4°C both for convenience, but also to avoid repeated freeze-thaw cycles.

Comment: @gaspanic that's good to know, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is perfectly fine. Many companies sell PCR Master Mixes (granted, without primers):

- [Thermo Fisher](https://www.thermofisher.com/order/catalog/product/K0171)
- [Sigma-Aldrich](https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/life-science/molecular-biology/pcr/pcr-master-mix.html)
- [BioRad](https://www.bio-rad.com/featured/en/pcr-master-mix.html)
- [Promega](https://www.promega.com/products/pcr/taq-polymerase/master-mix-pcr/?catNum=M7501)
- [Qiagen](https://www.qiagen.com/us/products/discovery-and-translational-research/pcr-qpcr-dpcr/pcr-enzymes-and-kits/end-point-pcr/taq-pcr-master-mix-kit/)

If you choose to make your own, make sure it's stored at -20°C, and be sure to aliquot it so it's not going to be subjected to multiple freeze/thaw cycles. Obviously you should mix it well before aliquoting, but even after thawing I would vortex it to make sure all of the components are well-mixed. Make a 2X master mix, and adjust to a final 1X concentration in the PCR tube with your DNA sample and nuclease-free H<sub>2</sub>O.